# How to get Pivot Table to work with a category hierarchy defined in a second table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm attempting to build a pivot table for expenses in excel. The source data is from Expensify, which just treats categories as a flat list. It looks like this

```
2019-11-02  CHAPTERS    9.99    Entertainment
2019-11-02  Canadian Tire   9.99    Gas
2019-11-15  Jimmys Coffee   9.99    Coffee and Tea
```

As it happens we want categories to have a hierarchy. I've created a category table for the hierarchy:

```
    Car - Repairs & Maintenance, Transportation, Essential
    Car insurance, Transportation, Essential
    Clothing, Everyday, Essential
    Coffee and Tea, Discretionary, Other
```

(Ignore whether coffee is a discretionary expense). I intend is that my pivot table would use the category table to lookup the parent levels:
Coffee and Tea would find it's parents as Discretionary and Other. When done there should be a simple hierarchy for use in the pivot table.

My first attempt to do this is a VLookup: `=VLOOKUP(D2, CategoryTable!$A2:$C47, 3)` - this, of course, works brilliantly well on the first row. My naive follow-up would just be a fill down command. Which increments every row number. So the second `=VLOOKUP(D3, CategoryTable!$A3:$C48, 3)`, etc. Of course, what I want is for the array `CategoryTable!$A2:$C47` to remain invariant and only the row number of the lookup itself to increase.

With an expense spreadsheet over several years, we might have 1000+ entries I can't do this by hand.

Ideally, there would a clever way to define a function once for an entire column. However - that's my programming brain speaking. In practice, I don't think this exists.

The pivot table interface suggests that I can combine data from two sources in the data manager. That feels a lot like SQL programming.

What is the cleanest, simplest and most maintainable solution?

Comment: You need to lock your CategoryTable.  Use CategoryTable!$A$2:$C$47.  The $ tells Excel not to change when you fill down.    Alternatively you can name the RANGE which also helps when you are troubleshooting.

Comment: Jim this is a fair of an answer - Thanks. By using a named range I was able to avoid the FillDown problem. The only thing missing then - it would nice just to tell excel this formula applies to all cells on the column.

Comment: Copy the first cell, select the rest of the column range and paste.  The formula will be filed.

Comment: Thanks Jim. The programmer in me is uncomfortable with this kind of approach. If a column had a formula and not just cells then when we add another 1000 rows of expenses it would work. Also if the spreadsheet works well, for us then my wife will be sharing it with people with less Excel experience I want it designed to be human friendly. That's asking a great deal of excel.